# how to redirect to the login page after idle time of spring session from all clients

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, war

i have use auth2 and spring security.i want to logout from all the clients when after the session idle time out passed.there's a cookie based authentication mechanism(authorization code flow).please help me to solve this issue.i want a code to logout with out putting idle time out in client it self,can i handle it from auth server side?the clients are prime face.the applications are run on jboss as war file.

i have tried put this on client

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class OauthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Value("${AUTH_BASE_EXTERNAL_URL}")
    private String authServerExternalUrl;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("login**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl(authServerExternalUrl + AppConstants.LOGOUT_URL).deleteCookies("JSESSION").invalidateHttpSession(true)
        ;
        http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/logout");
    }
    
}
```

it was successfull,but i want it do from auth server ,and override session idle timeout for all client in auth server,can i do that ? and i want to give error message in login page when idle timeout login page is built in thymeleaf

Comment: 1: there is no such thing as 'spring session', there is a webapp (servlet container/javee server)  session. 2: Nothing PrimeFaces related (and not JSF either imho)

Comment: thanks for update.is that http session?how to change the idle time out of spring boot war file?

Comment: No idea, I use plain javaee... Search engines are your friend